# Install Ubuntu 10.04 On An Expresscard Drive On MBP

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, external-hard-drive, macbook-pro, expresscard

I have a macbook pro (4,1) and an external SSD that is in my expresscard slot on my macbook pro. I would like to install Ubuntu 10.04 on the SSD and be able to boot into it from my macbook pro (ideally from holding the option key on start up and selecting the ubuntu OS)

Can someone please give me some guidance?

What I have tried already is installing Ubuntu straight from the Live CD onto the SSD (reformatting it and everything) and then booting into it but when I get to the point where I can select which OS I want to boot into OS X comes up once and Windows comes up twice (I have a partition on my HDD). At that point if I go into OS X and look at the SSD it is not readable by the OS.